Quantum two-body problem for particles with different potentials
The usual quantum two-body problem consists of two particles with the same potential $V(x)$ and its solution is obtained from the usual Schrödinger equation (SE),
$$
i \ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi(x_A,x_B,t) = \left[- \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m_A}  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_A^2} - \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m_B}  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_B^2}  \ + \ V(|x_A-x_B|) \right] \psi(x_A,x_B,t)
$$
However, if the potentials of each particle are different from each other, i.e. we consider a quantum two-body problem of one particle with arbitrary potential function $V_1(x)$ and another particle with arbitrary potential function $V_2(x)$, where $V_2(x)$ is different from $V_1(x)$, what equation(s) do we have to solve? Would it be a single SE or two coupled SEs?

You confuse external potentials and the inter-particle potential/interaction. The latter obeys the Newton's third law.

In a genuine two-body system, translation invariance requires the interaction of the particles to be of the form $V(|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|)$.
If you have $V_1(\vec{r}_1)+V_2(\vec{r}_2)$ instead of $V(|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|)$, then in general,  translation symmetry is broken, which means that you do not actually have a two-particle system, but more like two particles in an external field.
A simple example is the approximate (clamped-nucleus) eigenvalue problem of helium. The Hamiltonian
$$
H=-\frac{1}{2m}\nabla_1^2-\frac{1}{2m}\nabla_2^2-\frac{1}{2M}\nabla_N^2-\frac{Z\alpha}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{R}|}-\frac{Z\alpha}{|\vec{r}_2-\vec{R}|}+\frac{\alpha}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|} \ .
$$
describes a three-body problem. However, in the clamped nucleus approximation, you set the mass of the nucleus $M\rightarrow\infty$ and treat $\vec{R}$ as a parameter (which I just set $\vec{R}=\vec{\emptyset}$):
$$
H_\text{BO}=-\frac{1}{2m}\nabla_1^2-\frac{1}{2m}\nabla_2^2-\frac{Z\alpha}{|\vec{r}_1|}-\frac{Z\alpha}{|\vec{r}_2|}+\frac{\alpha}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|} \ .
$$
So in this approximation, you treat the nucleus as a source of the external Coulomb field which traps the two electrons instead of an actual active particle: instead of the three-particle problem, you now have a two-particle problem in an external Coulomb field. The classical $Ze$ point charge with fixed position breaks the homogeneity of space, so total momentum is not conserved.
If there is no interaction between the particles, only one-particle potentials from the external source, then the problem is separable into two uncoupled one-particle problems:
$$
H=\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2m_1}\nabla_1^2+V_1(\vec{r}_1)}_{H_1}+\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2m_2}\nabla_2^2+V_2(\vec{r}_2)}_{H_2} \ .
$$
Energy is of course additive over these non-interacting subsystems, and the wave function is separable.

The potentials are generated by the particles, each particle generates a different potential of arbitrary (fictional), different shapes. I am confused when I see it called an "external potential", as if it was generated by something other than the two particles. The way I consider the problem there is no external field. There is no field other than what the particles are generating. Can you root out the source of my confusion? Thanks.

Am I right in saying the two particles are entangled because they have interacted?

Say one particle generates the usual potential $\sim 1/r$, the other particle generates a potential $\sim 1/r^2$. What is the form of the equations to solve? We don't have a single V function since there are two different functions, $\sim 1/r$ and $\sim 1/r^2$.

@saturn Entanglement (or even QM) is not related to this problem, you would encounter the very same issue in classical mechanics. If you have a genuine two-body problem (so you only have two particles in empty space, and nothing else), then the total momentum of the two particles must be conserved; this just means that the center of mass moves through the empty space as a free particle (as it should). The only potential energy function that can ensure this has the form $V(x_1-x_2)$, because then the force particle 1 enacts on particle 2 is the negative of the force particle 2 enacts on...

...particle 1. The sum of forces is then zero, from which the free motion of COM follows. In your example, particles 1 and 2 feel completely different forces which do not balance each other, so the COM accelerates. You should ask yourself: what would $r$ be in your above comment? Is it the distance of the two particles, or is it related to the absolute position of $\vec{r}_1$ or $\vec{r}_2$? In the former case, the question would make no sense physically. In the latter case, it means that you have an external source which acts differently...

...on the two particles (but then this is not a real two-body problem anymore).

Somehow I am still confused. Conservation of momentum is a must $-$ no external forces are acting on the two particles which are the only entities in space, so the center of mass cannot move (neither there is an observer to see it move, or to be a frame against which it moves, but that is a fictional problem, let's just leave it out). Where I get confused is why we can't have these two different potentials where $r$ is the distance between the particles. In what way it would make no sense physically? That is the point I cannot understand.

Yes, $r$ is the distance between the particles, not an absolute distance.

I struggle to see why we could not have an electron, generating a potential going as $\sim 1/r$, and a fictional type of particle, generating an electric potential going as $\sim r^{-1.7}$. Why could we not set up this problem and solve it.

@saturn Potential energy is always symmetric between particles. For e.g. the Coulomb case, particle 1 at position $\vec{r}_1$ generates a potential
$$
\phi_1(\vec{r})=\frac{q_1}{4\pi|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_1|}
$$
at point $\vec{r}$, so that particle 2 at $\vec{r}_2$ feels the potential energy
$$
q_2\phi_1(\vec{r}_2)=\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|} \ .
$$
We would get the same if we considered the potential generated by particle 2, tested on particle 1. In other cases, we may not have a potential, only a potential energy, but...

...it is always symmetric under the interchange of particles nevertheless (think of e.g. the harmonic interaction $\sim|\vec{r}1-\vec{r}2|^2$). I don't really understand your example: there is no such thing as $p_1$ interacting with $p_2$ as $1/r{12}$ and $p_2$ interacting with $p_1$ as $1/r^2{12}$: the interaction between particles is always symmetric and mutual. Maybe you are confused whether there should be two Schrodinger equations for the two particles? The answer to that is no, there is only one Hamiltonian and one Schrodinger equation for the correlated two-particle system.

Would you be able to answer the question seeing this as a purely mathematical problem not grounded in physics?

@saturn What do you mean 'not grounded in physics'? The problem is grounded in physics. You want to obtain a two-body Hamiltonian by quantizing a classical energy expression. If you want to conserve total momentum, then that classical energy expression cannot depend on $\vec{r}_1$, $\vec{r}_2$ in an arbitrary way, but only through the combination $|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|$. How would you construct a potential energy $V(|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|)$, in which the action of $p_1$ on $p_2$ is somehow not the same as the action of $p_2$ on $p_1$? There is no way.
